# ora-12170:tns:connection timeout occured after executing sql scripts

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

ora-12170:tns:connection timeout occured while executed nearly 5000 records via toad.Could any one suggest any method to rectify

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12170_tns_connect_timeout.htm

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh am using MySQL